# How to extract information of only each 3rd event?

Tags: c++

I would like to look only at every 3rd event if those satisfy some specific requirement. For example, in the event loop, if I have events with a value greater than 15, then I want to extract information only of each 3rd such event. And if the event has value less than 15, then I want to have information of each event. Thank you!

I am a beginner, so I have only a "theoretical" idea of what I want. I searched around and could not find a similar problem.

Comment: Make an event adapter, this is an in-between class that receives all events and generate the same events. And let that adapter class filter out the events you don't want to forward. (Side note I usually try to make designs that do not rely on events at all)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, thanks for your comment. So there is no easier way than including designs? I googled about event adapter and it is a whole new world...

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain words. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, yes, actually I have discussed this with rubber duck and it helped me out to logically figure out what the steps are to achieve wanted result, however I have a technical problem with implementation of what I have written down and told to the rubber duck debugger... Could you please suggest me a platform where I could get technical help with C++?

Comment: It might help us if you have some actual code to show. E.g. how do you connect to your events now (which technology do you use etc)

Comment: Stackoverflow is strictly for questions and answers. For more general, informal discussions, the only platform like that I know of is comp.lang.c++ on Usenet, the grand-daddy of all these "platform"s.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it's simply a for loop for the events 
`for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){}` and inside of this loop I want to implement that if i > 15, then `cout` only every 3rd event, and if i < 15, then `cout` each of them

Comment: well, this is not exactly how it is , but if I can just `cout` the wanted information, then I could proceed to further steps as well

Comment: Pop quiz: do you know what you get if you take an integer, divide it by 3, and get the remainder of that operation? Do you know what happens if you check if the remainder is a particular value, let's say is 0, and you keep doing it with for the values of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and so on..? Do you know how often you'll triumphantly conclude that the remainder, when dividing `i` by 3, is 0? And what happens when you do this in combination of checking whether `i` is above or below 15, and then proceed accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best way to do that in real world applications, but if you do some simple app, you can do this using if-else statements

```
std::uint8_t counter = 1;
for (;;) {
  const auto event = get_event(); // there we retrieving our event
  if (event.value < 15) { /* do what you want with event */ }
  else {
    if (counter % 3 != 0){
      ++counter;
     }
    else {
     counter = 1;
     // do what you want with event
    }
  }
}
```

Here, we get our event in loop, checking if event value is greater than 15, or not. If it's greater, we do something on every 3rd event, otherwise, do something on every event.